# Push Notification Solutions for self-hosted applications (no API key)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

I'm building an open source application which is intended for users to self-host. Now, I would like to add push notifications on Android and iOS that would be sent from the self-hosted server application. Is there any alternative push notification service that does not require an API key (FCM, APNS) or per hosted instance registration (PushBullet) for this use case?

I've googled for this, but the only thing I've come across which even remotely resembles this is Pushjet.

Open source projects seem not to rely on Push Notifications, which is a shame considering how many great things can be done with them. I would really appreciate any and all suggestions.

To clarify, the project can't use Firebase, PushBullet, APNS or similar because all of these either require the developer to publish an API key in their app (Firebase) or require the user to register their clients and servers individually with a service like Pushbullet.

This question is specifically about avoiding this registration requirement and using some "public push" type service (if one exists).

Some examples of exactly what I'm trying to avoid:

- https://julienrenaux.fr/2015/06/25/ios-android-push-notifications-100-free-and-self-hosted-for-wordpress-using-cordova-and-ionic/
- https://home-assistant.io/components/notify.pushbullet/
- https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-push-proxy/blob/master/README.md

For anyone who's curious, the project is here: http://gitlab.mccollum.enterprises/icing/

Comment: May be [this](https://www.quora.com/Can-an-Android-device-send-Push-notifications) will help

Comment: You can use Firebase (Firebase Cloud Messaging) or Azure Web App (Notification Hub). You can define by 2 ways: send via your host, or your code should be dynamic secret key and guide user to config their host.

Comment: I've used FCM and I really like it, but it requires the application to be registered. I'm looking for a service that may use Firebase somehow itself, but doesn't require any type of registration or special marking in the source code. Perhaps the server and client simply pass the same UUID in the API calls or similar to distinguish. The traffic would either be non-sensetive or encrypted.

Comment: @KG6ZVP OK, I know your problem. But I really don't know your purpose, once user built their app, they should be equipped essential knowledge, step-by-step FCM (self-host) configuration tutorial is not a good case? I've thought about building a web service as the central of connection included handling 3rd Party (such as PushBullet, we get Access Token), then response back to your app. So it's really hard to implement.

Comment: The application is targeted at people who are barely geeky enough to download something and install it. Requiring someone to setup FCM not only fails on ease of use, but the goal is to target an in-browser QR code with deep links to an instant app that can receive push notifications. This means that the Google Play version of the app has to be able to work with whatever server they have which doesn't come with a FCM API key. It's tricky.

Comment: I should clarify that the instant app obviously wouldn't receive push notifications, but that the same code would be used for the instant and installable apps.